# Infinitesimal generator of a Markov process acting on a measure

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Short version: The transition operator of a Markov process can act on measures (on the left) or functions (on the right). The infinitesimal generator acts on functions. Is there a way to understand the infinitesimal generator's actions on measures? What type of object is the result?

**Update (see more below):** I'm basically asking for accessible references discussing the *adjoint* of the infinitesimal generator.

---

The transition operator $P_t$ of a Markov process can act on two types of objects:

- On the left, it acts on measures. If $\mu$ is a probability measure of the initial state $X_0$, then $\mu P_t$ is the probability measure of the state $X_t$ after time $t$.
- On the right, it acts on functions. If $f$ is a (nice enough) function, then $P_t f$ is "the expected value of $f$ after time $t$", i.e. $P_t f(x) = \mathbf{E}_x[f(X_t)]$.

The infinitesimal generator $G$ of the process is defined as acting on (nice enough) functions $f$ as
$$
G f := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{P_t f - f}{t}.
$$
This suggests that we could more generally define $G$ as acting on measures as
$$
\mu G := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\mu P_t - \mu}{t}.
$$
My question is: does the above definition make sense? What type of object is the result? Is there a standard reference I can read to learn more?

---

Here's what I have so far. For any particular value of $t$, the inner expression $\nu_t := (\mu P_t - \mu)/t$ is a signed measure. Intuitively, if $\mu$ is a probability measure, $\nu_t(A)$ measures the "mean net rate of probability flow into $A$" as the state distribution transitions from $\mu$ to $\mu P_t$.

But the limit $\nu_0 := \mu G = \lim_{t \to 0} \nu_t$ need not be a signed measure. For example, consider the the Markov process on $\mathbb{R}$ that always moves right (positive) at rate 1, and let $\mu = \delta_0$ be a point mass at $0$. This has generator $G f = f'$. Then I think $\nu_0$ is $-\delta_0'$ (using distributional derivatives), because its action on function should be
$$
\nu_0 f = \mu G f = \delta_0 f' = f'(0).
$$

This leads me to guess that in general, $\mu G$ is a linear functional, assuming that $\mu$, $G$, and the chosen function space are all nice enough. But this begs the question of what "nice enough" means here. Is there a treatment of this topic for more general Markov/Feller/similar processes?

---

**Update**

I have learned the map $\mu \mapsto \mu G$ is called the *adjoint* of the infinitesimal generator. For diffusion processes, this seems well-studied (see e.g. the Fokker-Planck equation), but I haven't been able to find an accessible discussion of it for more general continuous-time Markov processes.

One question that comes to mind is, "For what functions $f$ is the functional $\mu G := f \mapsto \mu (G f)$ well defined?" But this is basically the same as, "What is the domain of the infinitesimal generator $G$ (acting on functions)?" And this is known to not have a nice answer in general, so maybe there's not much more to say.

Comment: This reminds me a little of methods that arise in machine learning. You can try to model a random variable by simulating individual random variables (Markov Chain Monte Carlo) or model the flow of the measure (and typically work only with approximate measures in a restricted family - so called variational inference). Eg. https://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/hoffman20a/hoffman20a.pdf

Comment: One defines the adjoint semigroup (which acts on measures) $P_{t}^{*}$ of a Markov semigroup $P_{t}$, simply by dualizing: $\int P_{t}fd\mu=\int fdP_{t}^{*}\mu$